# Есть ли способ отключить мультиарендную (Multitenant) опцию?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Используем docker образ для Oracle БД 12.2. По умолчанию мультиарендная (Multitenant) опция включена.

Есть ли способ отключить эту опцию?

Нужна поддержка только для одного приложения, то есть нет никакой нужды в создании подключаемой БД (*PDB*).

<sub>Свободный перевод [Is there any way to disable oracle Multitenant feature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60657575/6571020) от участника [@mki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11861247/mkl)</sub>

Comment: Интересно откуда такой перевод: `Multitenant` --> `мультиарендную` ? ;)

Comment: Перевод  мультиарендность для Multitenant взят из [оф. белых бумаг](http://www.oracle.com/assets/multitenant-wp-t-2995359-ru.pdf).

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/60657575/6571020

Answer (score 6):

Прежде всего следует учесть:

- Не мультиарендная (*non-CDB*) архитектура [начиная с выпуска 20c больше не будет поддерживаться](https://mikedietrichde.com/2019/09/17/3-pdbs-included-with-oracle-19c-and-desupport-of-non-cdbs-with-20c/).
- Mожно пользоваться мультиарендной (*CDB*) архитектурой с одной подключаемой БД (*PDB*) без мультиарендной (*Multitenant*) лицензии. Начиная с выпуска 19c, эта возможность будет [расширена до трёх PDB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dblic/Licensing-Information.html#GUID-0F9EB85D-4610-4EDF-89C2-4916A0E7AC87) в одном контейнере (CDB).

Короткий ответ -- нет никакого способа отключить мультиарендную (*CDB*) архитектуру.

Чтобы вернуться на классическую не мультиарендную архитектуру, надо установить новую БД выбрав опцию *non-CDB*. Затем мигрировать все данные из сушествующей БД. Например с *Data Pump* [expdp/impdp](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-data-pump-overview.html#GUID-47B26B0B-3C95-4182-ACDF-2EEDD577FC9E) или любым другим инструментом для миграции/репликации данных.

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60659349/6571020) от участника [@ChrisSaxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>